# How do I know if I have new Azure DevOps Features?

Tags: azure-devops

Referencing the [publication of new features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-173-update), I modified my YAML for multi repo trigger support, but they aren't kicking off.

Is there a way to determine our tenant has Sprint 173 Features?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Comment: Hi, not get your latest information, is the answer below helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: This was useful, thank you

Comment: Hi @GotTheWongGuy, If the answer is useful, we can accept it as answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Next Steps section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-173-update#next-steps) of the article you referenced:

> These features will roll out over the next two to three weeks.

As long as this sprint scope was announced on August 3d, I guess you're good to go by August 24th at last. And no, I suspect there's no way to find out whether the changes were rolled out to your particular account other than to try it out.